# applescript or shell script way to i. e. grep an applications "status" after i. e. killall -STOP it

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, kill-process

If I pause an applications by

```
killall -STOP
```

it, is there a way to read this "status" for later use? I want to write a short script that checks if the application is already stopped and if so start it again via

```
killall -CONT
```

and if not I want to be able to pause it.

Comment: Use something like `killall -d` or `pgrep` to discover the process IDs of the target processes, then use `ps` to discover the state of the processes that have those IDs.  `ps` will show the state of a process as the letter "T" if the process is stopped.  Run `ps -j` manually to see an example of the state (in the STAT column) being shown along with a bunch of other stuff.  For scripting it's easier to tell `ps` to show only the state for a given `<pid>` by running `ps -o state= -p <pid>`.

Comment: I made a script out of your suggestions. It works, thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like that. With this script you are able to pause and unpause a program.

```
set shellOutput1 to do shell script "PROCESSNAME='<name of the process>'; GREPPID=$(pgrep $PROCESSNAME); if [ -z $GREPPID ]; then echo '1'; else echo '2'; fi; exit 0"

if shellOutput1 contains "2" then

    tell application "Finder"
        set visible of process "<name of the process>" to false
    end tell

end if

set notificationName to "<program name>"

set shellOutput2 to do shell script "PROCESSNAME='<name of the process>'; GREPPID=$(pgrep $PROCESSNAME); if [ -z $GREPPID ]; then echo '3'; exit 0; else PSSTATUS=$(ps -o state= -p $GREPPID); if [ $PSSTATUS == 'T' ]; then killall -CONT $PROCESSNAME; echo '1'; else killall -STOP $PROCESSNAME; echo '2'; fi; fi; exit 0"

if shellOutput2 contains "1" then

    tell application "Finder"
        set visible of process "<name of the process>" to true
    end tell

    display notification notificationName & " wieder gestartet!" sound name "default"

else if shellOutput2 contains "2" then
    display notification notificationName & " angehalten!" sound name "default"
else if shellOutput2 contains "3" then
    display notification notificationName & " läuft nicht!" sound name "default"
end if

return shellOutput2
```